# AJAX console window with ANSI/VT100 support?

Tags: python, ajax, vt100

I'm planning to write gateway web application, which would need "terminal window" with VT100/ANSI escape code support. Are there any AJAX based alternatives for such a task?

I'm thinking something like this: http://tryruby.hobix.com/

My preferred backend for the system is Python/Twisted/Pylons, but since I'm just planning, I will explore every option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

[AnyTerm](http://wiki.kartbuilding.net/index.php/Anyterm)

[AjaxTerm](http://wiki.kartbuilding.net/index.php/Ajaxterm)

[WebShell](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mressl/webshell/)

Answer (score 7):

There's also [Shell In A Box](http://shellinabox.com).

Comment: I used AjaxTerm for a while, now I prefer shellinabox. Less limitations.

Answer (score 3):

AjaxTerm has a terminal, with mostly felicitous terminal emulation, done on the Python backend (it just pushes display updates to the client Javascript).

The [AjaxTerm](http://antony.lesuisse.org/qweb/trac/wiki/AjaxTerm) website has been down for some time, but you can still find it [packaged](http://packages.debian.org/etch/ajaxterm) in Debian.