# Web control center with Python

Tags: python, web-applications

I'd like to create some web based control center where I can start processes and watch statistics, logs and outputs. Also I would like to run something like an interactive Python console on the webpage.

I'd don't know any web development yet, but I know Python. Something Python based would be nice.

Could you please suggest which tools and methods I should learn to implement this? Ideally minimal effort to achieve first results.

Comment: you wish to implement something like e.g. [nagios](http://www.nagios.org/)?

Comment: Well, similar. Except that what I display would be very simple (Logs, State-Flags) which I'd calculate with Python. Also I probably won't need much more than running programs. So this is not such much for professional system monitoring, but rather to provide convenience for some custom tasks I have to do for work.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a custom tool for your specific needs, you might want to develop your own small [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) based wep app and use [celery](http://celeryproject.org/) to spawn managed tasks.  You can store your log in files or in models.  This will probably require a lot of effort if you are new to web development....

If you want to cut programming time and would like to start with a generic solution, you might be able to start with this: http://code.google.com/p/python-loggingserver/

Some other non-python options are [cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) or [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/)

***Update:***

See also: [DjangoTaskScheduler](http://code.google.com/p/djangotaskscheduler/)

A web based python console is a very tricky option and considered as a risky and non standard addition.  You should consider this thoroughly because it might have security and stability implications on your server and apps.  If you do decide to use one, you can check out the links below:

- https://github.com/sympy/sympy-live
- [AJAX console window with ANSI/VT100 support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244750/ajax-console-window-with-ansi-vt100-support)

The probable alternative would probably be ssh (see also: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mressl/webshell/ )

Comment: Does Django allow features like live logging display and maybe even inclusion of a live Python console? So is learning Django and HTML all I need? :)

Comment: added some info to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want [Sage Math](http://www.sagemath.org). It does almost everything you have described through a web interface.

Sage math would be the main focus of the web interface. If you just want to embed a python shell, I think ipython would A good place to start, but you would have a lot more development to do to get where you want to go.

Comment: It seems like a Maths package?! Can it help me to create a web interface?

Comment: Sage Math is a Python based  web interface to Python and other math packages.  It supports launching threads for parallel processing and plots and graphs.  If you're looking for a plugin to an existing web site, it might be too complex for you.